# How to format a JSON object as Pandas Dataframe?

Tags: python, json, pandas

I'm loading up a json, and accessing a nested object, *plotArray*:

```
with open(testArray, "r") as rf:
    arr = json.load(rf)
    plotArray = arr['data']['plotArray']
```

plotArray has the following structure:

```
{'headers': ['p_id', 'e_id', 'l_id', 'o_id'], 'data': [[1, 3, 5, 9]]}
```

I simply want to a pandas dataframe with the json key 'headers' as column names and the values for the key 'data' as an actual entry under the columns.

thanks for considering my question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following should work:

```
df=pd.DataFrame(plotArray['data'], columns=plotArray['headers'])
```

Output:

```
>>>print(df)

   p_id  e_id  l_id  o_id
0     1     3     5     9
```